# undefined error when trying to parse an input from a form. Javascript

Tags: javascript, undefined, nan

I've removed my JS from the main page and have included it instead.  I'm trying to obtain a value from a form field and use it to update the decimal places that a conversion might be altered by.

I've tried a couple of options, all of which I thought would work but I either receive a NaN error or an undefined error.

HTML form:

```
<form id="convertFormID_JS" name="convertForm">

    <div class="ourContactFormElement">
        <label for="decPlaces">Decimal Places?</label>
        <input autocomplete="off" type="number" name="decPlaces" id="decPlaces" class="required digits" onkeyup="convertUnits()" />
    </div>
```

JS function:

```
function roundResult(value, places){
var multiplier = Math.pow(10, places);
return (Math.round(value * multiplier) / multiplier);}
```

Where I'm trying to obtain the value: (this is within the main function)

```
var decPlaces = parseInt(document.getElementById("decPlaces").val());
```

The aim is to allow a user to change the number of decimal places.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using jQuery on this page? Because you mixed pure javascript `document.getElementById()` method with jQuery collection method `val()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById("decPlaces").val()` is invalid it should be `document.getElementById("decPlaces").value`

[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val1) is a utility function provided by jQuery to get/set the value of an element, since in this case you are not using jQuery you need to get the value of the input element using the [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-value) property